# Omit HTML but keep <br> tags in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formatting, view

I need to display user comments, omitting HTML to prevent attacks (when custom styled elements can be posted as comments)
The only thing, i would like to keep by displaying - is 
 tag

I displaying the comment in this way:

```
<p class="content"><%=h comment.content.gsub(/\n/,"<br/>") %></p>
```

Comment is suppossed to be saved in database without any markup

Line ending are converted to "br" tags

But, sure, they are gone, because of **=h** output mode.

Is there a way to kill all html, except "br" tags ?

Comment: I don't understand.  If you are removing all the tags when you put comments into the database, why are you removing them again when you display them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either use [sanitize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize) which keeps only specified HTML tags:

```
<%= sanitize comment.content.gsub(/\n/,"<br/>"), :tags => ['br'] %>
```

or (in your case preferably) change the order of both and do the [html_escape](http://apidock.com/rails/ERB/Util/html_escape) yourself:

```
<%= html_escape(comment.content).gsub(/\n/,"<br/>") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use `white_list` plugin. It's safety for XSS attacts and you will be able to control list of allowed tags